# JavaScript declared global variable can't assign in method

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables, hoodie

I have some JavaScript code where I have a variable that I've declared outside the function however I can't seem to assign it.

I've looked around and am doing the generally accepted thing of assigning outside the function but still have issues.

Any ideas?

```
var numberPeopleSignedIn;

function setWaitTime(id, currentTimeToMinus){

var peopleAvailable = [];

  hoodie.store.findAll('barber')
  .done(function(object) {
      object.forEach(function(barber) {
      if (barber.statusInOut == "signedIn") {
        peopleAvailable.push(barber);
      }
      numberPeopleSignedIn = peopleAvailable.length;
    });

  });


console.log(numberPeopleSignedIn);  //This is returning undefined

}
```

Comment: For the gazillion time - asynchronous execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findAll()` is returning a delegate. Meaning the console.log is being called before the `.done()` function when `numberPeopleSignedIn` is still undefined.